# Template Installation

Tags: templates, joomla, installation

I am having a hard time finding and getting a free template to work. I have tried many free templates but none of them worked properly. Currently the content of my joomla website is the default one that comes with the installation when someone chooses "Install sample data"

I always check that the template is compatible with my joomla version (3.4.3) and my php version (5.3). I also check that the template does not need other extensions or plug-ins to work.From Joomla Administration > Extension Manager I upload and install the template and then select it as default from the template manager.

But then the default navigation toolbar and many modules disappear. I am trying to understand whether apart from the template itself I also need some "Sample" content that is appropriate for the specific template, like some of the paid templates provide.

Can someone clarify to me the steps to install a free template. Perhaps provide a link to one along with instructions?

Comment: Well of course modules disappear when you change templates, they probably have different position names, they may or may not use bootstrap, and in some cases they add very complex templating frameworks.  Learning to use a template framework can be really hard but if you don't want to change anything it can be okay. They often give you a lot of configurable options. Really depending on what you want you can copy protostar and create your own more understandable one. But if you are not a designer it's likely not going to look like a designer made it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good demo template that you can customize

http://yootheme.com/themes/downloads -> master template

or master template with demo content

If you will like it - my advise - buy good commercial template from yootheme.